# Finding a basis for $W^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Define an inner product on $\mathbb{P_4}[x]$ over $\mathbb{R}$ as follows:
>   $$
>   \langle f,g \rangle = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
> $$
>   Let $W$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{P_4}[x]$ consisting of $0$ and all polynomials with degree $0$: That is, $W= \mathbb{R}$. Find a  basis for $W^{\perp}$.

**My attempts:**

$\mathbb{P_4}[x]= a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 +a_3x^3 + a_4x^4$

Now $p_1 =1$, $p_2 = x$, $p_3 = x^2$, $p_4 = x^3$, $p_5 = x^4$.

Now $p_1= w_1$ so that $\| w_1 \|^2 = (w_1,w_1) = (1,1)$.

Now $\| w_1 \|^2 = \int_{0}^{1} 1 \cdot 1 \,\mathrm{d}x = 1$.

Similarly  $w_2 = p_2 - \frac{\langle p_2, w_1 \rangle w_1}{\|w_1||^2} = (x - \frac{1}{2})$.

Is this partial answer correct or not?

Please help me; any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=k\in W$ and $g\in W^{\perp}$ then

$$\langle f,g\rangle = k\int_{0}^{1} g(x) dx=0$$

that is

$$a_0+\frac12a_1+\frac13a_2+\frac14a_3+\frac15a_4=0$$

then

$$g(x)=a_1(x-1/2)+a_2(x^2-1/3)+a_3(x^3-1/4)+a_4(x^4-1/5)$$

therefore a basis for $W^{\perp}$ is given by

$$\{x-1/2, x^2-1/3, x^3-1/4, x^4-1/5\}$$

Comment: thanks @gimusi  but im not getting  how  u  write $a_0+\frac12a_1+\frac13a_2+\frac14a_3+\frac15a_4=0$??  how it come

Comment: from the condition that $\int_0^1 g(x) dx=0$, I’ve skipped all the intermediate steps but they are trivial

Comment: okk im getting now .... but  liitle more doubts $a_0$  is  not in g(x) ..then how  its  come  on

Comment: @stupid $$g(x)=a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 +a_3x^3 + a_4x^4$$ then use the condition found for the coefficients that is $$a_0=-\frac12a_1-\frac13a_2-\frac14a_3-\frac15a_4$$.

Comment: ohh  i missed  that ,,,thanks  a lots @gimusi

Comment: I didn’t give all details since you can find out easily by yourself! You are welcome, Bye